# Amber and localstorage, asJSON?

Tags: json, local-storage, smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

I want to store with Amber ([on-line IDE](http://amber-lang.net/))  an OrderedCollection in the localStorage of a web browser and later retrieve it.

#### Creating a test data object

```
| coll hcoll |

coll := OrderedCollection new.
coll add: 'abc'.
coll add: 'xon'.

hcoll := HashedCollection new.
hcoll at: 'en' put: 'English'.
hcoll at: 'fr' put: 'French'.
hcoll at: 'ge' put: 'German'.

coll add: hcoll.
```

#### Storing the test data object in localStorage

localStorage is a key-value store in the browser. The values have to be strings.

```
localStorage setItem: 'coll' value: coll asJSONString.


"We set coll to nil to indicate that we 
are going to retrieve it back from the localStorage"

coll := nil.
```

#### Getting back the stored value

a *printIt* of the following

```
localStorage getItem: 'coll'
```

gives

```
 '["abc","xon",{"en":"English","fr":"French","ge":"German"}]'
```

This is a JSON string.

How do I get back the OrderedCollection  *coll*?

Use the JSON parser built into the browser

```
JSON parse: (localStorage getItem: 'coll')
```

The result of a *printIt* is

```
an Array ('abc' 'xon' [object Object])
```

and

```
(JSON parse: (localStorage getItem: 'coll')) class
```

is

```
Array
```

The third element of the Array

```
((JSON parse: (localStorage getItem: 'coll')) at: 3) class
```

is a

```
JSObjectProxy
```

### Question

How do I get back the Smalltalk representation for an arbitrary JSON object (containing JavaScript Arrays and Objects, OrderedCollections and HashedCollections, Dictionaries in Smalltalk)?

### Note

http://www.json.org

JSON is built on two structures:

- A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object,  dictionary, hash table,  or associative array.
- An ordered list of values. In many languages, this is realized as an array, list, or sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A printIt of

```
  SmalltalkImage current readJSObject: 
            (JSON parse: (localStorage getItem: 'coll'))
```

gives back

```
    an Array ('abc' 'xon' a Dictionary ('en' -> 'English' , 'fr' -> 'French' , 'ge' -> 'German'))
```

**Comment**

```
(JSON parse: (localStorage getItem: 'coll'))
```

gives a JSProxyObject which is then converted to Amber objects by the method #readJSObject: . This method just redirects the call to an underlying JavaScript method.

Comment: Note: In an earlier version of Amber `#readJSObject:` was called `#readJSON:`